# Initializing a doubly linked list from array parameters

Tags: c++11, data-structures, parameters, constructor, doubly-linked-list

C++ noob reporting in. I'm trying to write a function that will create and initialize a doubly linked list using values that are stored in two different arrays. Here's how my linked list class is set up:

```
class node {
   public:
   node *prev;
   node *next;
   int key;
   char type;
};
```

and here's how my dList class (containing various functions to alter my linked list) is set up:

```
class dList {
private:
   node *head; // dummy head
   node *tail; // dummy tail

public:
   dList() { // default constructor, creates empty list
     head = tail = NULL;
   }

   ~dList() { // deconstructor
     node *ptr = head;
     while (head != NULL) {
       head = head->next;
       delete ptr;
     }
     tail = NULL;
   }

   dList(int arrayNums[], char arrayChars[], int size); // parametrized constructor, initialize list w/ contents of arrays

   void addFront(int k, char t); // creates new node at front of list

   void addBack(int k, char t); // creates new node at back of list

   node *search(int k); // searches list for occurence of int parameter and returns pointer to node containing key

   void find(char t); // outputs all keys that have type equal to character parameter, front to back

   void moveFront(node* ptr); // moves node pointed to by parameter to front of list

   void moveBack(node* ptr); // moves node pointed to by parameter to back of list

   void out(int num, char = 'f'); // outputs first int elements of list, starting at front or back depending on char parameter

   void sort(); // peforms a quick or mergesort on items; list should be in increasing order based on integer key

};
```

I need help implementing my parametrized constructor. Could someone tell me if the function I have now is written correctly? I think it is, but when I run my program, it runs forever--a clear problem. Here's my function as-is:

```
dList::dList(int arrayNums[], char arrayChars[], int size) { 
  node *newNode = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    if (head == NULL) {
      newNode = new node;
      newNode->key = arrayNums[i];
      newNode->type = arrayChars[i];
      newNode->prev = NULL;
      newNode->next = NULL;
      head = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    }

    else { // needs work!
      newNode = new node;
      newNode->key = arrayNums[i];
      newNode->type = arrayChars[i];
      newNode->prev = tail;
      tail->next = newNode;
      tail = newNode;
    }

    if (i == (size - 1)) {
      tail->next = NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!

EDIT: here is my main.cpp (code I'm using to test my dList.cpp file)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "dList.cpp"
#define SMALL 200
#define MAX 100000
#define ROUNDS 100
int main(){
    int i, x[MAX];
    char ch[MAX];

    for(i=0;i<SMALL;i++) {
      x[i] = 2 * (SMALL - i);
      ch[i] = 'a' + (i % 26);
    }
    dList A(x,ch,SMALL), B;
    A.out(10);
    node *tmp = A.search(2*SMALL-8);
    A.moveFront(tmp);
    A.out(10);
    A.moveBack(tmp);
    A.out(10);
    A.find('b');
    A.sort();
    A.out(10);
    A.out(10,'b');
    A.addBack(500,'d');
    A.addFront(501,'z');
    A.out(10);
    A.out(10,'b');
    B.addFront(1,'a');
    B.addBack(2,'b');
    B.out(2);

    for(int j=0; j<ROUNDS; j++){
      cout << endl << "round " << j << endl;
      for(i=0;i<MAX;i++) {x[i] = 2*MAX-i; ch[i] = 'a'+ (i%26);}
       dList A(x,ch,MAX);
       node *tmp = A.search(2*MAX-8);
       A.moveFront(tmp);
       A.moveBack(tmp);
       A.sort();
       A.out(10);
       A.out(10,'b');
    }
}
```

Comment: `~dList()` destructor calls `delete` on the same pointer multiple times. The second time exhibits undefined behavior, by way of double destruction.

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using to test this, the one that runs forever (the main method?).

Comment: also it is simpler to set newNode->next  to NULL in the else part instead of have a special case i == (size-1)

Comment: @gkamal I added main.cpp in my main post.

Comment: I can't find any obvious issue.  You can try with smaller values for ROUNDS & MAX - to verify if there is some code issue or it is taking very long to run for large values.  You can also add more logging or use gdb to step line by line to figure out where it gets stuck (runs forever).

Comment: @gkamal thanks! I think my issue is in a different function--just wanted to make sure my code was good.